# Remove block for theme

Tags: layout, grid-layout

I have a problem removing a block on the mobiletheme.

The issue is that the block is added by an cms page xml layout update which is already almost at the end.

I haven't found an observer to remove the block after the layout is loaded but not rendered. It's not working to use

```
<reference name="content">
<remove name="blockname"/>
</reference>
```

in the xml of the pagetype.

Comment: Would it work to specify the theme/layout in the cms page xml layout update so as to not apply it to the theme you want it removed from?

Comment: have you try controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before events

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458611/update-layout-programatically-in-magento-event-observer

Comment: what block are you wanting to remove?

Comment: @DaChronDon 
The cms page (it's about many cms pages) is for both - desktop and mobile. So I cant just set it up for one theme. I guess it's not possible to add an xml layout update only for one theme.

Comment: @AmitBera
I tried 2 or 3 observers but not controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before. I gues sit's to really but I'll try.

Comment: @JasonTipton
A custom added block by an cms page xml layout update. We want to improve the mobile-pageloadtime by removing some teasers which are added by a xml layout update n the cms page.